# How to shift a block by exactly one space the right/left in Sublime

Tags: sublime-text-2, sublime-text-3, sublime-text

One can move a block of text using `ctrl+ ]` or `cmd + ]/[`. Is there any way so that I can move a block by exactly one space to left or right.

Thank You

Comment: Even if there isn't a specific option to do that you could change the indentation to 1 space, and indent or unindent to achieve what you want, and then set it back to normal. Maybe you even want to leave it like that if you need to move things by 1 space all the time.

Answer (score 0):

On a Mac, you can make your cursor span multiple lines by holding `Option` and dragging it down, then insert spaces. You could have the cursor be discontiguous by clicking on different columns on different lines, kind of like how you would select multiple items in a file browser. I don't know what the equivalent would be on other OS's. (You mention both `ctrl` and `cmd` keys)